# Conditional query of the tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

ALL,

Consider the following database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE players(playerid integer primary key, playertype integer, ....);
CREATE TABLE scoretype1(scoreid integer primary key, scorename varchar);
CREATE TABLE scoretype2(scoreid integer primary key, scorename varchar);
CREATE TABLE scoreforplayerstype1(playerid integer, scoreid integer, value double, foreign key(playerid) references players(playerid), foreign key(scoreid) references scoretype1(scoreid));
CREATE TAble scoreforplayerstype2(playerid integer, scoreid integer, value double, foreign key(playerid) references players(playerid), foreign key(scoreid) references scoretype2(scoreid));
```

Now the problem:

Is it possible to get the score values for all players in one query or I have to do 2 queries for type 1 and type 2? I'm looking to have a score name and score value for a player.

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to do it using JOIN-s, but you have bad design. Imagine, that every time you have new type you must create new tables and change queries.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan is right. Why not combine score type 1 and 2 int oa single table with an additional column to record if the row is type 1 or 2?

Comment: Is it the only reason? ;-) There will be no new type added. But the information will be duplicated since the players already have the type field and aslo some scoring have the same name but different meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P1.PLAYERID, S1.SCORENAME, J1.VALUE
FROM PLAYERS AS P1
INNER JOIN SCOREFORPLAYERSTYPE1 AS J1
ON J1.PLAYERID = P1.PLAYERID
INNER JOIN SCORETYPE1 AS S1
ON  S1.SCOREID = J1.SCOREID
UNION ALL
SELECT P2.PLAYERID, S2.SCORENAME, J2.VALUE
FROM PLAYERS AS P2
INNER JOIN SCOREFORPLAYERSTYPE2 AS J2
ON J1.PLAYERID = P1.PLAYERID
INNER JOIN SCORETYPE2 AS S2
ON  S1.SCOREID = J1.SCOREID
```

Comment: is it better or worse performance wise then the solution below?

Comment: Just tested and performance-wise its much faster than the other solution. So I'd select this one. Thank you.

Comment: surprised this would be faster since it has 2 SELECTs, 4 JOINs and a UNION. Compared to 1 SELECT AND 4 JOINS.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.playerid
    ,p.playertype
    ,IFNULL(sfp1.value, sfp2.value) AS value
    ,IFNULL(st1.scorename, st2.scorename) AS scorename
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN scoreforplayerstype1 sfp1 ON p.playerid = sfp1.playerid
LEFT JOIN scoreforplayerstype2 sfp2 ON p.playerid = sfp1.playerid
LEFT JOIN scoretype1 st1 ON sfp1.scoreid = st1.scoreid
LEFT JOIN scoretype2 st2 ON sfp2.scoreid = st2.scoreid
```

That should do it, but as the comments suggest, you should rethink your table structure.

Comment: can u rewrite it using simple WHERE clause? I don't like to use something I don't understand and I have an additional filtering condition that might screw it up. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not filtering the result set at all so nothing to put in a WHERE clause. The information you want is in multiple tables so JOINs are absolutely necessary.

Comment: so it can't be rewrited with SQL-92 standard?

Comment: AFAIK that is SQL-92 compliant